# List tables from Omnis database

Tags: sql

I m migrating data from Omnis Database to SQL Server using SSIS. I can connect Omnis Database with ODBC driver and query tables, but i want to automate the process so i need to retrive all the tables from a database using sql statement. On other databases, i'll usually do this way :

under MySQL i ll do

```
SHOW TABLES
```

under postgresql

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
ORDER BY table_schema,table_name;
```

But don't know the syntaxe with Omnis Db. How can i acheve this?

If it s possible i also need to get column data type information...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
_odConn.Open(); // Where this is my Omnis Odbc driver connection object

var tableDT = _odConn.GetSchema("TABLES");
foreach (DataRow r in tableDT.Rows)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Database: " + r[1].ToString()); // This will always be "OMNIS"
   Console.WriteLine("Table Name: " + r[2].ToString()); // This is your table name, ie, "ACTIVITY"
   Console.WriteLine("Object Type: " + r[3].ToString()); // This will always be "TABLE"
}
```

To get a list of column definitions, do the same but use `GetSchema("COLUMNS")`. The content of each of the columns is not documented as far as I know, but here are what I use:

```
column #   Content
3          Column Name
5          DataType
6          Precision (or length)
11         Comment or Description
16         Ordinal position of column
```

Comment: Thanks, i ll test that as soon as i go back on the project.

Answer (score 0):

You could try linking to the ODBC data using Excel, it seems to know how to "see" all the tables and columns.